# How to describe this brick in order to identify and buy matching ones?

Tags: brick

This is my first post here so apologies if this isn't the type of question that should be asked.

I am undertaking some work on my house in Liverpool UK which was built (we think) in 1994. We (and our building contractor) are finding it very difficult to find matching bricks. One of the difficulties I am having is the terminology used.

In terms of colour I'm not sure if my bricks are considered red, buff, orange etc.

In terms of texture I'm not sure if my bricks are dragfaced, sandfaced, creased, distressed etc.

I have uploaded a picture here:
[image: https://ibb.co/znw8ZKk]

**What words would I use to describe this brick to a tradesman/dealer in order to find the best match?**
(A small part of me hopes that some genius on the internet would be able to tell me the exact name/brand for this brick!)

Comment: Bricks are usually made close to where they are used . Investigate which brick makers have plants in your area. Then send your picture to these along with brick size and the year your house was built. The brick makers wil know all the terminology

Comment: https://www.ibstockbrick.co.uk/brick-selector/.  Get started here 

Comment: @Kris this is the kind of tool I'm trying to use but I'm not sure of the colour/texture etc that my brick qualifies as.

Comment: http://www.brickstore.org.uk/.   These guys look like they can help with brick matching

Comment: I don't know bricks that well, but I know from experience with many products that the type of torn surface you see fits the term "dragfaced" very well.

Comment: It is extremely hard to get a brick that resembles the others...I'd find a place that is out of sight, try to pry a brick out, replace THAT with a new brick, and take the weathered one as a replacement.

Comment: You will not find a perfect match.